# Как реализовать вот такую запись function1().function1(); ?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как реализовать такую запись? Скажем, есть функция, коротая возвращает элемент:

```
 var $ = function (id) {
    if (id[0] == '#') {
      id = id.slice(1);
    }
    return document.getElementById (id);
  };
```

А есть функция, которая что-то делает с этим элементом:

```
var function bg (elem, color) {

elem.style.backgroundColor = color;
};
```

Используются они вот так:

```
bg($("id"), "цвет");
```

Как изменить эти функции, чтобы они работали, как в jquery:

```
$("id").bg("цвет");
```

Ещё хотелось бы знать, как сделать возможность писать изменение цвета много раз на один и тот же элемент:

```
$("id").bg("цвет1").bg("цвет2").bg("цвет3") ...;
```

Comment: @Станислав Далинин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
var MyObj = function(obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
};

MyObj.prototype.bg = function (color) {
         var id = this.obj;
         if (id[0] == '#') {
           id = id.slice(1);
         }
         var a = document.getElementById(id);
          a.innerText = color;
          return this;
};

var $ = function (id) {

    return new MyObj(id);
};

$('#test').bg('0xFF0000').bg('green');
```

html:

```
<p id="test">test</p>
```

[ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/y13f68sw/)

Дальше дорабатывайте по вашим требованиям.

Comment: И что вот такая запись будет работать`  $("id").bg("цвет1").bg("цвет2").bg("цвет3")`?

Comment: Обновил пример.